# Conversion of "scaled points" (TeX lengths) to "PDF points"

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdf, tex-core, lengths

If I'm not mistaken, sometime within the last two years the conversion factor has changed from 65,536 (2^16) to 65,782. (At least in LuaLaTeX for the lengths in "pdf literals").

Why the change?

With the fonts it is probably different. 10pt seem to still correspond to 655,360 (10 x 65,536) ... !?

What is going on here?

EDIT: The question is probably based on an incorrect assumption, which came about because I could not imagine that there are two different factors that differ only marginally from each other. Nevertheless, I leave the question up, because it might be helpful to other users.

Comment: There's been no change: what gives you the idea there is?

Comment: 1pt has always been 65536sp and a Postscript point  1bp is 72.27/72 pt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A TeX Point (`1pt`) is 65536sp in all releases of all engines.

A PostScript/PDF Point is known as a "big point" (`1bp`) in TeX and is 65781sp (not 65782sp) This again applies to all releases.

You can test

```
\message{\ifdim 65536sp = 1pt YES\else NO\fi}

\message{\ifdim 65781sp = 1bp YES\else NO\fi}


\bye
```

which will log `YES YES` with luatex or pdftex, xetex, etc.

Comment: @Joseph I have used the factor 65536 for the pdf literals in some packages until now. (And I remembered that the packages worked fine in my tests.) Now I noticed that the graphical elements are all of a sudden slightly off. After I changed the factor to 65781, it works perfectly.
Though, now that I think about it... I remember that I changed the factor relatively late. It could be possible that I originally used the correct factor and then after finishing and testing the packages I changed it to 65536 (without checking the output again), falsely assuming this must be the correct factor.

Comment: @keth-tex why are you working in sp at all and needing these numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. (Maybe because I do almost all the programming in Lua?) At least on the Lua side you get the sizes all in sp. Lengths from nodes (glyph dimensions, kerns, glues, …), from tfmdata, from tex (tex.hsize, tex.pagewidth, …), what have you. So when I want to use these lengths for pdf literals I have to convert to bp. And when I want some output (in terminal, log, …) in point (e. g. font size) I have to convert to pt. – Am I missing something??

Comment: @keth-tex "Working from Lua" is fine as an answer, thanks:-)

Comment: So sp are only used in LuaTeX and not in (La)TeX programming?

Comment: @keth-tex well you _could_ use them and fundamentally all lengths are really integer values corresponding to sp but you rarely need them as all the convert functions such as `\the` or `\showthe` show the value as `pt` (with sufficient accuracy to give the exact underlying integer sp value) you typically only see the sp value if you explicitly cast to an integer `\count0=\dimen0` would put the `sp` value of `\dimen0` in to `\count0`